# On Windows, why can't perl find a module I installed using ppm?

Tags: perl

I'm using ActivePerl-5.18.4.1804 on Windows 7.  I have a script that requires [XML::RSS](https://metacpan.org/pod/) module.  I did install it using `ppm`, but I have always the same error message:

> `Can't locate XML/RSS.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14/i686-cygwin-threads-64int /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14/i686-cygwin-threads-64int /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14 /usr/lib/perl5/5.14/i686-cygwin-threads-64int /usr/lib/perl5/5.14 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8 .) at bao1.pl line 3. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at bao1.pl line 3.`

Comment: Did you use the ppm from one install of Perl, but try to use the module using another install of Perl?

Comment: Can't locate XML/RSS.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14/i686-cygwin-threads-64int /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14/i686-cygwin-threads-64int /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.14 /usr/lib/perl5/5.14/i686-cygwin-threads-64int /usr/lib/perl5/5.14 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8 .) at bao1.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at bao1.pl line 3.

Comment: this is where I call the module use XML::RSS;

Comment: The module is correctly installed in C:\Perl\site\lib\XML

Comment: That error message is not from ActiveState's `perl`. It is from Cygwin's. Decide which one you want to use, and adjust your path appropriately.

Answer (score 6):

Using `ppm`, you installed the module in ActiveState Perl distribution's `lib`. However, the `perl` binary you are trying to run is from Cygwin.

That means, Cygwin's `bin` directories appear before ActiveState's `bin` directories in your `%PATH%`.

[Edit your `%PATH%`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310519) so that `C:\Perl\site\bin;C:\Perl\bin` appear ahead of any Cygwin related directories if you wish to use ActiveState's `perl`.

Or, invoke `perl` using `C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe` to make sure you run the right `perl`.

You should seriously consider becoming familiar with how your chosen OS works before attempting to become a programmer.

Comment: How can I install the module and run it with Cygwin please?

Comment: By installing the module using Cygwin's `cpan` instead of ActiveState's `ppm`. Make sure you are running the right `cpan` because there will also be a `cpan` that came with ActiveState.

Comment: I did this but it still don't work, I have a bunch of errors like Can't test without successful make

Comment: Edit your post, show the command you ran, paste the error messages you got instead of making vague statements in comments. Did you install `make` for Cygwin? Did you install `gcc` for Cygwin? First, understand how your preferred environment works.